# Create Custom Object List accessible to Scene files

Tags: properties, operator

I want to make a obj list of some sort, let's say in the scene, I want to mark a object as high poly and for that I am trying to implement a List to contain those objects. The problem I am facing right now is that in sample script you see, the list "is_HP" contains obj I append let's say with an operator, Script just shows what action I am doing in addon, but as I save and reopen the blend file, the list becomes empty, as the list was just use during the run of the script,

So what I want is a List but which is accessible in Scene, so if I append that object to the list and save the blend file, I would later be able to access the contents of that list in the same blend file.

Because that's how scene variables normally works.

So I want to know how to make that list too storable in Scene, rather than only during the run of the py/addon.

[image] file.

Answer (score 1):

Blender already has a built-in feature for that - [Collections](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/index.html). So you don't need to reinvent the wheel here.

You can group objects in many different ways with collections, they are part of .blend file structure already and will be saved with no problems and have loads of features. Also many other features in Blender can use collections in various ways. An object can be in multiple collections at the same time, there is plenty of convenient functionality related to moving, assigning and re-assigning objects to collections and it's very easy to work with objects in collections with Blender's Python API. For example you can access all objects in a collection: `bpy.data.collections['Some Collection Name'].objects`

If you really don't want to use the awesome functionality of collections that happens to be exactly what you describe you need, you could also just store the list as a custom property of some data block in Blender. Let's say I want to store selected objects with my active scene:

```
bpy.context.scene['my_custom_list'] = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects]
```

That's it:

[image]

My scene now has a list that will be saved with the file. Here they are:

[image]

Comment: I understand Collections and their properties fairly well, But I don't want to implement it using collection , Because In a big scene when you have already collections structures, you don't wanna clutter it with extra collections, that's why I am trying to implement a background tags features. Hope it clarify what I mean to ask

Comment: Why? You can have nested collections. This way really huge amounts of collections can be easily managed. Also, collections do not need to be linked to any scenes or view layers to exist, so you can also keep them out of your scene. It is a good way to group objects in Blender for any purpose. I'll update the answer with more.

Comment: Although, I am aware that collections can be created without linking to scene, Collection property is good no doubt, but I have use cases for marking objects with list, like let's say I wan to mark another object as low poly of current, instead of creating a new collection for the linking those high polys, I can just access the list and the variables without working with Collection.

Comment: Anyways I tried something with your list method, I can't create the bpy.context.scene['my_list'] without assigning it to the list comprehension like you did, Can you explain how to create it without always assigning, as I will be appending objects in it in future. Consider this from a operator perspective, not script, if I'm using operator to write "bpy.context.scene['my_list'] = [o  for o in bpy.context.selected_objects]" , it will reassign new objects and remove old ones.

Comment: What I want is like: "Create a new property list with given name, then append what I like", but when I create a list like this "bpy.context.scene['my_list'] = [] " and try to append something, it says no append functionality or can't append objects, only supports int,float...

Comment: OK, I did not know it works like that. Seems like it's best to retrieve the list from the property to a regular Python list, work with it however you need to and then save it back to the property. It doesn't work like a regular list even if you assign a list of objects to it - I cannot reverse the list while in the property for example when I test it, or remove objects from it same way I can with a regular list.